# How to get this data using the DRY concept?

Tags: javascript

I am working with an API that returns a list of ingredients for each item. Instead of having the ingredients in an array, it lists them in their own key:value pair like so:

```
{ingredient1: "item", ingredient2: "item2"}
```

My first thought was to use a For-loop, but I'm not really sure how to execute that. In my head it would be something like this(this doesn't actually work):

```
for(let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {console.log(data.ingredient + i)}
```

This, of course, is viewed as a mathematical operation not concatenation. How would I go about this correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: As an alternative to trying to construct the property names, you could loop through the object's keys instead. E.g., [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: `data['ingredient' + i]`, but that is very ugly way to do anything. Why not loop key -> value of object and do something then?

Comment: what is your target state, what are you trying to achieve, also are you okay with your solution to support modern browsers only?

Comment: I would loop the key:value pairs, but there is more data than just the ingredients. I should have probably mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the structure of the object.  If it's something like this:

```
var recipe = {
    name: "Item name",
    ingredients: {ingredient1: "item", ingredient2: "item2"}
}
```

Then you can just do:  `Object.values(recipe.ingredients)`

If it's instead something like:

```
var recipe = {
    name: "Item name",
    ingredient1: "item",
    ingredient2: "item2"
}
```

Then you could do:

```
Object.keys(recipe).filter(k => k.startsWith('ingredient')).map(v => recipe[v])
```

```js
var recipe = {
    name: "Item name",
    ingredient1: "item",
    ingredient2: "item2"
}
console.log(Object.keys(recipe).filter(k => k.startsWith('ingredient')).map(v => recipe[v]))
    
recipe = {
    name: "Item name",
    ingredients: {ingredient1: "item", ingredient2: "item2"}
}
console.log(Object.values(recipe.ingredients))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {console.log(data[`ingredient${i}`])}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know you cant reach object's property with variables like you try.

So there would be two ways:

> 1) To map object with this method
>
> in your case data is your object

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
```

> 2) Map object with your approach ( which is not good practice I can
>   say )

```
for(let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    let val;
     switch(i){
      case 1: val = data.ingredient1; break;
      case 2: val = data.ingredient2; break;
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over object keys

ES6:

`for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) { }`

OR

`for (const value of Object.values(obj)) { }`

Try :

```
var obj = {ingredient1: "item", ingredient2: "item2"};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) { console.log(value)}

//Output:
//item
//item2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nowhere near as complex as the other answers make it seem...
There is a loop syntax specifically for this. It is called [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

> **MDN**
>
> The `for...in` statement iterates over all non-Symbol, enumerable properties of an object.

---

```js
for (const item in data) {
  console.log(data[item]);
}
```

In which `item` holds the key, which you can in turn use to index into `data`.

Answer (score 0):

I would normalize them as array anyway, and then operate on that:

```
const getIngredients = (ingredients) =>
  Object.entries(ingredients).reduce((acc, [k,v]) =>
    (k.startsWith("ingredient") && acc.push(v), acc), []);
```

At this point you can pass to the function the object that contains the ingredient, and you will have an array you can iterate as usual.

For example:

```
let recipe = {foo: "bar", ingredient1: "item", ingredient2: "item2"};

let ingredients = getIngredients(recipe));
// if the ingredients are in a property, you can just pass it, e.g.
//
// getIngredients(recipe.ingredients));

console.log(ingredients); // ["item", "item2"]
```

This approach uses [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and array's [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods.